# Is Coalesce a function of ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Is the COALESCE a function of the ANSI SQL especification? Is it supported by the major relational databases?

Comment: One caveat, just because a function is an ANSI SQL standard, doesn't mean that most RDBMS's support it. For instance temporal logic is an `ANSI SQL:2011 SQL standard` and there's only a few databases that are supporting it so far (although many are catching up or have similar-ish or partial temporal functionality). `COALESCE()` is everywhere though and a standard (92, I think).

Comment: @JNevill Good point, and as an example of that, `COALESCE()` is not available in MS Access

Comment: `COALESCE()` is ISO/ANSI standard SQL.  It is available in almost all databases (all if you don't include MS Access).

Comment: Whenever a DBMS supports `CASE` it also supports `COALESCE` and `NULLIF`, both are shortcuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

From the article:

> Some think that you need to use COALESCE because it is the only one that adheres to the ANSI SQL standard.

and Yes.

Answer (score 4):

The ISO/ANSI SQL standard specification **ISO/IEC 9075-2:2023(E), Annex H, SQL mandatory feature taxonomy**, lists `CASE` and `COALESCE` as mandatory features:

```
F261     CASE expression
F261-04  COALESCE
```

`COALESCE` is also an ISO/ANSI SQL reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, COALESCE is defined by the ISO/ANSI SQL standards.